# What is the origin of "pan" as a slang term for "face"?

Tags: etymology, slang

I was think of posting a picture of my ugly *pan* here instead of the gravatar, when I started to wonder, why is it my ugly *pan*? The slang term *pan* meaning face occurs chiefly in phrases such as *ugly pan* and *smack in the pan*, suggesting that is not very complimentary.

Green's *Dictionary of Slang* has several different meanings including the female pudenda, the mouth, the head and the anus but suggests no etymology.

Does anyone have any idea where the term came from?

Comment: It's interesting that you mention a meaning including the head. In the Brythonic Celtic languages (Breton, Cornish and Welsh), the word "pen" means head. Cornish and Welsh developed into separate languages from a common, Brythonic language that was spoken across Britain, before the arrival of English. Maybe this was the origin of *pan*?

Comment: @Tristan, you may well be on to something there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The book [*American Slang*](http://books.google.com/books?id=Ow7JpC1NcesC&pg=PA364&lpg=PA364&dq=pan+face+origins+slang&source=bl&ots=us3kPy2mqx&sig=p-AhYsbvMi8N5t6qun4cDmj8O7o&hl=en&ei=I6dBTpusMczRiALv2c2XBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&ved=0CGMQ6AEwCTgU#v=onepage&q&f=false) gives the following entry for *pan*:

> 1. The face. *MUG*. *Too great for them to keep their pans shut*. (1923+)

This seems to be when *pan* first entered American slang. From there, it went on to form words like [deadpan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpan#Etymology) (recorded in 1927). Only one site gave a hint to the actual origins, though. In this [question about the origins of "deadpan"](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/19/messages/1382.html), it is written that:

> The key to "deadpan" is the use of "pan" as theatrical slang for "the face" (reflecting the use of "pan" to mean "skull," found as early as 1330).

Going off of this, there seems to be some support. The [Word Origins](http://www.word-origins.com/definition/skull.html) page for *skull* says:

> The Old English word for ‘skull’ was hēafodpanne, literally ‘head-pan’. It has never been firmly established where its Middle English replacement skull came from, but is seems more than likely that it was borrowed from a Scandinavian language (Swedish and Norwegian have skalle ‘skull’).

So the old word for *skull* gave *pan*, which was adopted to mean *face*. From there, *pan* entered American slang in the early 1920s.

Comment: It could be added to this that in the Scandinavian languages, (Icelandic+Faeroese+Swedish/Norwegian/Danish) _panna/panne/pande_ is the normal word for ‘forehead’. This is quite obviously the same word as OE _(hēafod)panne_, and also as any other kind of pan—‘forehead’ and ‘frying pan’ are cognate homonyms in the Scandinavian languages (though dictionaries normally list them as seperate lemmata).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's from the Hebrew פּנים, transliterated as "panim:" — oddly, a plural —, which means "face". (If there were a singular, it would be transliterated as pan.)

Comment: Do you think it is from Yiddish (the more likely source of things originally Hebrew)?